# What is the ideal database to use for an application that will hold unique user data of an expandable list of dictionaries?

Tags: web-apps, javascript, database, sql, mongodb

I created a fitness tracker web app, currently I am using mongodb as the database. In my app each day will be a new dictionary of various keys that I will then push to a list in the User Schema. I wanted to use Mongodb but each document will can only have a maximum size of 16 megabytes, so it will get filled very quickly. I want it hold as much data as possible to be able to log the information as a chart so the user will be able to see their progression over time. I have only used mongodb but I'm willing to learn any. What would be the ideal database to hold such data.

Comment: The common way would be to store each day in a separate record, then you don't hit the size limitation.

Comment: Ah yes only thing is that I want to eventually deploy this app and allow users to create an account thus having many documents for each account would be huge. Would it work fine? I originally had it where each document is a different day like you said but that only worked well for a single user myself.

Comment: That is the way databases work. You have a large number if records. Make sure you create at least one index for the fields you use for retrieving data.

Comment: Oh okay I just thought it would be inefficient. Guess I can make a crude brute mongodb database where each document represents a workout (day) and have a user Id key in order to match a user with his account when retrieving their data. Any other recommendations? Thx for the help.